# Laravel 4.2 - PHP Error reporting turned off

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel 4.2 application runs happily with undefined variables or array indexes.

I have placed

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

in many places in my code in an attempt to get this happen.

The php.ini contains

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Debugging is true in app.php.

I have grep'd all of the Laravel and vendor code and my code to look for locations where error reporting may have been turned off, but none seems relevant.

Non-Laravel web applications on the same server crash and/or report properly for these kinds of errors.

PHP is 5.6.8 on Fedora and 5.5. on Centos.

Why do I not see any notices, warnings? With this level of error, PHP should be throwing exceptions on undefined variables and array element accesses.

E.g. for something like `$object['member']` where the array "$object" has no key "member" should cause an error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Show code which should throw an error